# How many trainers in the anime have Legendary Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon

Tobias has darkrai and Latias. I also remember another guy from the battle frontier having an articuno which fought Ash's Charizard. Are there more trainers with Legendary Pokemon in the anime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well firstly, the person you seem to be referring to with the Articuno is *Noland*. The Articuno he uses against Ash was befriended by him and wasn't technically **captured** and hence, not his pokemon.

Since you specified *Anime*, I will stick to mentioning trainers only from the Anime who have Legendary Pokemon. At the same time, I think it is fair to disregard Evil Teams who managed to control Legendary pokemon/ Trainers who have befriended Legendary Pokemon and even used them in battle.

The following trainers in the Anime have Legendary Pokemon

- [Brandon](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pyramid_King_Brandon): He is the Frontier Brain of the Battle Pyramid and considered to be the strongest Frontier Brain in the Battle Frontier. He owns a **Regirock, Regice and Registeel**.
- [Tobias](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tobias_(Sinnoh)): He is the Winner of the *Lilly of the Valley Conference(Sinnoh League)*. He owns a **Darkrai and Latios**.
- Random Trainer in the *Lilly of the Valley Conference(Sinnoh League)*: In [Episode 182](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DP182) in the anime, we see a random trainer registering a **Heatran** for the Pokemon League. However, we never see this trainer or Heatran in any of the matches in the tournament apart from this episode.
- [Nurse Joy part of the *Gym inspection Agency*](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Inspection_Agency): In a [Diamond & Pearl Special](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/SS025), we see Nurse Joy use a **Latias** against Brock's brother Forrest.
- [Gladion](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gladion): He is Lillies Brother and Ash's reccuring Rival in the *Sun & Moon* anime. He has a **Type: Null** which later evolves into a **Sylvally**.